# Pointing to a correct assembly reference on CSC

Tags: c#, metadata, alias, csc

I have two MSIL Dll (Lib1.dll & Lib2.dll) with same name of class and namespace and methods but they have different names (The Assembly Metadata Name is same) . I'm trying to build new assembly and use this assemblies (using csc (c# compiler)) . So it causes me to use `extern alias` feature that uses like this :

```
extern alias Lib1;
extern alias Lib2;
```

The problem is they (Lib1 & Lib2) have a same name on their metadatas and if I use

```
csc ...  /r:Lib1=Lib1.dll /r:Lib2=Lib2.dll ...
```

It will build but the result is in error because all of the instance on methods point to Lib1.dll !

As I search on the internet I understand that it is not possible to change their metadata name . And I know it is not reasonable to use `ILASM` & `ILDASM` to change their metadatas .

So is there any way to point at the correct assembly on CSC or something else to solve it ?!

Note : I use .Net Framework 4.0